# Фильтр вывода записей в WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, вёрстка

Сделал AJAX фильтр записей WordPress.
Для простоты включил в него только чекбокс, который включает сортировку записей по порядку (ASC).

Вот функция-обработчик в `functions.php`, которая делает вывод записей через функцию `get_posts()`:

```
function true_filter_function(){
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'pizza',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
);

// условие: включено ASC - сортировка по порядку
if ( isset( $_POST['in_order'] ) && $_POST['in_order'] == 'on' ) {
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $args  );
echo "</pre>";

$pizza = get_posts( $args );

return $pizza; }

add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
```

Это фильтр и вывод постов на странице:

```
            <!-- Фильтр -->
            <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="in_order"/>Включить сортировку по порядку</label>
                <button>Применить фильтр</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
            </form>
            <div id="response"></div>

            <!-- Вывод постов -->
            <?php
                $pizza = true_filter_function();

                foreach ($pizza as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <div class="post__item">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

jQuery-скрипт:

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#filter').submit(function(){
    var filter = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'), // обработчик
        data:filter.serialize(), // данные
        type:filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('button').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
        },
        success:function(data){
            filter.find('button').text('Применить фильтр'); // возвращаем текст кнопки
            $('#response').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

В `functions.php` сделал `print_r( $args  );`. При включении чекбокса "Включить сортировку по порядку" и нажатии на кнопку "Применить фильтр" видно, что в массиве `$args` меняется значение ключа `'order'` с `'DESC'` на `'ASC'`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но на порядок вывода записей это почему-то никак не влияет.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'pizza',
'orderby'     => 'ID', // <= Сортировать по убыванию чего
'order'       => 'ASC',
);
```

Comment: Добавил этот параметр, но все по-прежнему. Там дело не так в сортировке, как в том, что работа фильтра по изменению массива $args почему-то никак не влияет на вывод постов

Comment: Поле id и в вашей таблице именуется id? Или поправили под себя и не работает,

Comment: Поле id именуется id, под себя не правил. Но даже без этого параметра там же сортировка по умолчанию по дате публикации записи происходит.

Comment: Вот забыл, id надо указать как ID

Comment: Спасибо, поправил на ID, но не помогло.
Мне кажется с выводом постом через get_posts() что-то нет так делаю